# How to left justify text in Bash

Tags: bash, printf, justify, text-justify

Given a text, `$txt`, how could I left justify it to a given width in Bash?

Example (width = 10):

If `$txt=hello`, I would like to print:

```
hello     |
```

If `$txt=1234567890`, I would like to print:

```
1234567890|
```

Comment: You tagged this with `printf`, so you pretty much knew the answer already. Why not check out how `printf` works?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the `printf` command, like this:

```
printf "%-10s |\n" "$txt"
```

The `%s` means to interpret the argument as string, and the `-10` tells it to left justify to width 10 (negative numbers mean left justify while positive numbers justify to the right). The `\n` is required to print a newline, since `printf` doesn't add one implicitly.

**Note** that `man printf` briefly describes this command, but the *full* format documentation can be found in the C function man page in `man 3 printf`.

Comment: @Jaypal, I have no idea what just happened or why, but I'm sure it's not your fault :)

Comment: Spatz, @Jay was apologizing for [the edit he made to your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8994148/revisions) which deleted all the text except the `printf` line from your answer (I'm sure the edit was not made with malicious intent, I'm just trying to clear up the confusion, that is all).  p.s., this answer helped me solve a problem I was having in one of my bash scripts, so thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-` flag for left justification.

#### Example:

```
[jaypal:~] printf "%10s\n" $txt
     hello
[jaypal:~] printf "%-10s\n" $txt
hello
```

Comment: LOL, I ended up adding an example to spatz solution. Oh man this is getting crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Bash contains a `printf` builtin:

```
txt=1234567890
printf "%-10s\n" "$txt"
```